# Bootstrap display 4 columns on large screen, 2 on extra small

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have in 1 row 4 columns. In extra small screen I would like to display it in 2 row. For other sizes can remain 1 row.

This is what I am trying:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
        4
    </div>
</div>
```

I have problem only when there is a long text in cell 1:

I want the result like this:

[image]

But when I have a long text I got the following:

[image]

And I would like to get the following:

[image]

Is it possible without creating two rows? The old layout is for big screen, I have to do this for mobile but without changing the old layout.

Comment: Can use "col-md-3 col-6", https://stackoverflow.com/a/61968250/1019435

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all '`xs`' css in two columns, works for me:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
        4
    </div>
</div>
```